# Can't get the session for Junit testing

Tags: session, servlets, struts2, junit, junit4

My Struts2 Action classes use the below code to successfully access the session

```
    ActionContext.getContext().getSession().clear();
```

However, when I try to use Junit to test my Action classes I get a NullPointer exception.
I have been reviewing some of the comments posted by others on StackOverflow and have been using the below code:

```
HttpServletRequest request;

HttpSession session;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {        

    request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    request.setAttribute("beanList", beanList);
    request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    Mockito.when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(session);

    Map<String, Object> contextMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    contextMap.put(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST, request);
    ActionContext.setContext(new ActionContext(contextMap));
}
```

However, it still throws a null pointer error. The system is able to successfully find get the context, but when it tries to get the session it dies on me.  I have also tries a few different ways to accomplish the same goal to no avail.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Mockito is great, but you don't need it for this case. The session is just a map. See my answer below for details. Also, your NPE is likely due to the fact that you aren't actually setting the session map in your ActionContext anywhere. You are only adding the HttpServletRequest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the dependency injection approach and change your action to implement `SessionAware`. Then, the Struts2 framework will inject the session into your action, such as in the example below. Finally, you can test by simply injecting a Map into your action.

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
  private Map<String, Object> session;

  public String execute() {
    // do actiony stuff
    return SUCCESS;
  }

  public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
    this.session = session;
  }
}
```

FYI, `ServletConfigInterceptor` handles performing this injection and the same kind of injection is available for accessing other servlet objects, such as the `HttpServletRequest` or the `ServletContext`.

Comment: This ended up working for me.  I just used the SessionAware in conjunction with the Struts2 MockHttpSession.  Of course, my boss just told me that theoretically my Action class should not be using the action class anyway(:  So now I get to rewrite my Action class without using the session!  Still good to know how to do this.  Thanks Steven.

Answer (score 4):

What about instantiating or mocking your session?

`session = mock(HttpSession.class);`

before calling

`Mockito.when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(session);`

Comment: Dooh! I just started using Mockito a few hours ago. . . I will see if that is the solution.

Comment: Nope.  Still throws the NullPointer exception.

Comment: I'm pretty new to all of this myself, but if I remember correctly, you'll also want to use the `when` statement at the point in your test that your code actually calls `getSession` not in your Setup method

Comment: And did you mean to mock the request twice?

Comment: Hmmm . . . the problem is that I call the .getSession() method from within the Struts2 Action class itself.  I can't put the test in the Action class.

Comment: Anywho, I will take a look at this when I get home later tonight (its 7pm here). Been looking at these screens all day . . . might be why I can't 'see' the right way to do it yet. Thanks Adam:)

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help when I can.  The below answer though gives some insight into this with Struts2 (which I haven't used).  I was just going off of what I knew about JUnit and Java.